# Javascript. Tree of hash char

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie in javascript. I'm trying to do a tree of hash ("#") in javascript. The output I would to have is something like:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

I know how increment the line with "for" cycle;
This is my code:

```
var s = "#######";
for (i = 0; i <s.length; i++)
console.log(s);
```

But I don't understand how can decrement the char "#" by string.

Can someone please explain this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your existing code, try the following:

```
var s = "#######";
for (i = 0; i <s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s.substring(0,i));
}
```

The `substring()` method of the string object (ie. your var `s`) returns a portion of the string starting at `0` (the first char) and ending at `i`, which increases by 1 for each iteration of your `for()` loop.

> But I don't understand how can *decrement* the char

Should be *increment*.